# Hibernate @OneToOne and ConstraintViolationException on one side of relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm just testing hibernate @OneToOne relation and validation on entities fields.
Here is my one side of relation:

```
@Table(name = "devices")
@Entity
public class Device extends BaseEntity  {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_type_id")
    private DeviceTypeEntity deviceType;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String serial;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "device",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @NotNull
    private Connection connection;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id")
    private List<DeviceStatus> deviceStatuses = new ArrayList<DeviceStatus>();

    // getters and setters

}
```

Other side of relation

```
@Table(name = "connections")
@Entity
public class Connection extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="connection_id", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank
    private String connectionId;

    private String hostname;

    @NotBlank
    private String ip;

    @Column(name="remote_port",nullable = false)
    private Integer remotePort;

    @Column(name="connection_time",nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "com.app.hos.persistance.custom.DateTimeUserType")
    private DateTime connectionTime;

    @Column(name="end_connection_time")
    @Type(type = "com.app.hos.persistance.custom.DateTimeUserType")
    private DateTime endConnectionTime;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id")
    @NotNull
    private Device device;


    // setters and getters
}
```

If I set null to 'connectionId' field in Connection class and save 'Device' object with that 'Connection' i.e.

```
  connection.setDevice(device);
  device.setConnection(connection);
  deviceRepository.save(device);
```

I am expecting ConstraintViolationException and it is ok for me. But I have noticed there is a device entity inserted into database. Why? 
I expect that if expception occure the transaction is rollback and there will be no enitity in database at all (no connection and no device inserted into db).

Comment: Why are you expecting `ConstraintViolationException`?

Comment: Because of the @NotBlank annotation over connectionId field

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You set `nullable = false` in Device Entity.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "device",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(nullable=false)
@NotNull
private Connection connection;
```

Comment: OneToOne do not accept nullable parameter but Column does. The problem is that if I put Column over Connection I received excpetion 'Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Column(s) not allowed on a OneToOne property'

Comment: Sorry You can @JoinColumn annotation and then set nullable false there. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although what suggested in the other answer fixes the problem from the application point of view, there is a bigger issue here i believe. When you define constraints on application level you mostly do it because you want to detect problems and violations as soon as possible. In this case you wanted to detect a constraint of `not null` at application level. But the fact that when this constraint wasn't checked, your application wrote data to the database   in a case when it shouldn't have, it means you are missing the *constraint on database* level. This is important and should be handled with bigger priority.